# Swift - weak self in didSet

Tags: swift, weak-references, didset

I rarely see people using `[weak self]` in `didSet`. Is there a reason for this?

I tried to use `[weak self]` in my `didSet` of a variable:

```
var data: Dictionary<String, Any>! { // [1]
        didSet { [2]
            self?.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
```

Either I put `[weak self] in` at [1] or [2], I still get the error: `Use of unresolved identifier weak`

Why is that? Is it illegal to use `[weak self]` for a `didSet` ?

Regards,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`didSet` is not a closure, you cannot use a closure syntax for it.

There is no reason to use `weak self` there. a `didSet` handler won't create ownership cycles in the same way a method doesn't create them.

Answer (score 6):

Don't do that.

It's nonsensical to use `[weak self]` because `didSet` does not capture anything and will never create retain cycles.